# EntityFramework : does IQueryable or IEnumerable get all the results at the first place?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I learned that IQueryable or IEnumerable datatypes do not return the results at the first place and only return them when needed. However when I open that object in the watch inspector I saw all the objects are there.

**Is there anything wrong in my code or it just showing because I had call it on the watch ?**

[When I view the **pendings** object in the watch dialogbox I saw all the list items but it shouldn't load at the first place. Is there anything wrong in my approaching or is it just showing because I had call it on the watch.]

```
 public IQueryable<PurchasePendingView> PurchasePendings() {
            var pendings = db.PurchasePendingViews
                             .Where(m => m.AccountStatusID != StructAccountStatus.Succeed); // when I view it in the watch dialougebox I saw all the list items but it shouldn't load at the first place. Is there anything wrong in my approaching or is it just showing because I had call it on the watch. 
            if (ApplicationEnvironment.DEBUGGING) {
                return pendings;
            } else if (IsMobileAccount()) {
                var showroom = db.ShowRooms.FirstOrDefault(m=> m.MemberID == employee.MemberID);
                if (showroom != null) {
                    return pendings.Where(m => m.ShowRoomID == showroom.ShowRoomID);
                } else {
                    return pendings.Where(m => m.CountryDivisionID == employee.CountryDivisionID);
                }
            } else { 
                //normal salary employee can see every detail
                return pendings;
            }
        }
```

**Note: Currently my lazy loading is off.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The collections are evaluated the first time you iterate through the results.

Since you're iterating through the results in the watch inspector, they are evalauated then.

Comment: so does it means that my query is actually loading nothing at the first place and at the end when return those to something it will load?

Comment: @user1542653 - No. It means that your method with return the IQueryable object and then the results will be loaded the first time the result is iterated over by the caller.

Comment: No, even when you return it, it will not load until some calling code iterates over the return.

Comment: yeah , understood . Like when i convert it to .ToList() or ToArray() or run a for loop.

Comment: Another thing I saw in my some queries that when I used take I didn't get the expected results. 'Take()' only take the first asked items then query on them based on the where() clause is it correct?

Comment: @user1542653 - That should be its own question.

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to demonstrate than to explain:

```
public class MeanException : Exception
{
    public MeanException() : base() { }
    public MeanException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
public static IEnumerable<T> Break<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    where T : new()
{
    if (source != null)
    {
        throw new MeanException("Sequence was evaluated");
    }
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new MeanException("Sequence was evaluated");
    }

    //unreachable

    //this will make this an iterator block so that it will have differed execution,
    //just like most other LINQ extension methods
    yield return new T();
}

public static IEnumerable<int> getQuery()
{
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    var query = list.Select(n => n + 1)
        .Break()
        .Where(n => n % 2 == 0);

    return query;
}
```

So, what do we have here.  We have a custom exception so we can catch it independently.  We have an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` that will always throw an exception as soon as the sequence is evaluated, but it uses deferred execution, just like `Select` and `Where`.  Finally we have a method to get a query.  We can see a LINQ method both before and after the `Break` call, and we can see that a `List` is used as the underlying data source.  (In your example it could be either some collection in memory, or an object that will go query a database and then iterate over the results when iterated.)

Now let's use this query and see what happens:

```
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before fetching query");
    IEnumerable<int> query = getQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("After fetching query");
    foreach (var number in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside foreach loop");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("After foreach loop");
}
catch (MeanException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception thrown: \n{0}", ex.ToString());
}
```

What you'll see if you run this code is the print before the query (obviously) the print after the query (meaning we just returned the query from a method and the mean exception was never thrown) and next the message that the exception was thrown (meaning we never got inside of, or past the end of, the foreach loop.

This is obviously a bit of a contrived example to demonstrate a concept, but this is something you'll actually see in practice often enough.  For example, if you lose your connection with the database after creating your data context you won't actually get an exception until you iterate the query, or if your data holder objects are out of date and don't match the DB any longer you'll get an exception at the same point.  In a less obvious example, if you hold onto the query for an extended period of time you will end up with data at the time you fetch the results of the query, not when you build it.  Here is another demonstration of that:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var query = list.Where(num => num < 5);
Console.WriteLine(query.Count());

list.RemoveAll(num => num < 4);
Console.WriteLine(query.Count()
```

Here we have a list of data, and count the number of items less than 5 (it's 4).  Then we modify the list (without changing `query` at all).  We re-query `query` and end up with a count of 1.